# Видимость let в теле switch case?

Tags: javascript

Есть следующая конструкция:

```
switch(val) {
    case '1':
        let sign = bar
        return ...
    case '2':
        let sign = foo
        return ...
}
```

При срабатывании этого кода вылетает ошибка

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'sign' has already been declared

Почему? Что, если я не хочу, чтобы переменная sign создавалась в каждом кейсе?

Comment: в кейсах можно просто фигурные скобки использовать или всетаки обьявить переменную 1н раз для всех

Answer (score 6):

> Директива let позволяет объявить локальную переменную с областью видимости, ограниченной текущим блоком кода  ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let))
>
> Блок инструкций (или сложная инструкция в других языках) используется для группировки нуля или более инструкций. Блок отделяется парой фигурных скобок ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA))

```js
function fn(val) {
  switch (val) {
    case '1':
      {
        let sign = 'bar';
        return sign;
      }
    case '2':
      {
        let sign = 'foo';
        return sign;
      }
  }
}
console.log(fn('2'));

function fn2(val) {
  let sign;
  switch (val) {
    case '1':
      sign = 'bar';
      return sign;
    case '2':
      sign = 'foo';
      return sign;
  }
}
console.log(fn2('1'));
```

Comment: В комментарии под вопросом, Вы всё правильно сказали. Дополните пожалуйста ответ вариантом с одним объявлением.